# Wrap post images with a link, not figure (image_send_to_editor doesn't work)

Tags: images, hooks, post-editor

The new version of WP wraps all images put into a post with a `figure` element, instead of `a href`. I tried to use this hook in my functions.php

```
if( is_admin() ) {
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wp_link_wrap', 10, 8 );  
function wp_link_wrap( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) {
    return '<a href="'. $url .'">'. $html .'</a>';
}}
```

but it changed nothing.

Comment: You can still add a link to images. Is that not working?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes, I can, but there is still a <figure> wrapped around both a and image.

Comment: Why is that a problem? It's valid HTML.

Comment: The gallery js plugin requires it to be a direct link. I could <figure> using JS, but this should be the solution, and it doesn't work for an unknown reason.